# How to split string taken as input and I want to separate it with commas like in the output

Tags: c

```
    char exp[50];
//  printf("Enter the postfix expression :");
//  scanf("%s", exp);
```

When the input is `567+*`, the desired output is as shown.
I need  to separate the input string in C; how to do that?

Output

```
5,
5,6,
5,6,7,......
```

Comment: Don't dual tag C questions with C++ too.  The answer in C++ is radically different from the answer in C.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon, and also about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  —— What have you tried?  Do you require the output in the variable `exp` or in another array?  It looks as though you want to print the intermediate results too, which suggests that the output should be in a separate array.

Comment: sorry but i need answer in both languages because i am working on the same problem

Comment: but right now in C Jonathan Leffler

Comment: Do you need the same code to work in C and C++, or do you need a native C solution and a native C++ solution?  The native C solution would probably work in C++ (but would be lousy C++ code); the native C++ solution won't work in C.  Also, don't mention just one of the two languages in the title; either mention neither or mention both.  And clarify in the question what sort of solution you need.

Comment: native solution for C right now

Comment: sorry it was my first post

Comment: Please edit the question to clarify your requirements.  We can't guess what you need – you have to say what you need.  Then we can clean up some of the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want to achieve by that - but you get it with a double for loop:

```
char exp[64];
scanf("%s", exp);

for(char* e = exp; *e; ++e)
{
    for(char* ee = exp; ee < e; ++ee)
    {
        if(ee != exp)
            putchar(',');
        putchar(*ee);
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

I assume that you insured by whatever means that the string in the buffer is null-terminated. If you cannot guarantee, you might want to check instead of for `*e` for something like `e < exp + sizeof(exp)` or `e < exp + maxLength` or combine one of the latter two with `*e &&`

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to copy one character from the original array plus one comma and print the result after each such addition, you can use two arrays:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char exp[] = "567+*";
    char res[1024];          // Plenty big enough

    char c;
    char *src = exp;
    char *tgt = res;
    while ((c = *src++) != '\0')
    {
        *tgt++ = c;
        *tgt++ = ',';
        *tgt = '\0';
        puts(res);
    }

    return 0;
}
```